# Maximum likelihood estimator Factor Analysis

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I'm looking for a good explanation for how to perform factor analysis using MLE. I'm aware of the `factanal` function in R, but I'm looking to calculate it manually step by step for learning.

I understand that the log likelihood function for $\Sigma=\Delta\Delta^t+\psi$ is:

$-\frac{n}{2}(\log|\Delta\Delta^t+\psi|+tr((\Delta\Delta^t+\psi)^{-1}R)$
and that I need to maximize that for both $\psi$ and $\Delta$ iteratively, but how exactly do I do that? Should I use the derivative?
I noticed the `factanal` used eigenvalues and I'm not sure why.

Any comprehensive explanation or reference would be very helpful.

Comment: check out the johnson and wichern multivariate text. it's probably in there.